# RegEx help grabbing the className off of a react/jsx element

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs

for example I have`<img className='class' src='somelink' />`
and I want to grab just `className='class'` I already tried `/ className='.+'[ |>]` Im traversing files looking for all classNames but this img example gives me everything including the `src='...'` what would be a good expression to give me all classNames and only the classNames with any possibilities inside the quotes?

Comment: I'm obviously super new with regex and don't understand it that well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `className='.+?'`. This will make the expression "lazy" instead of "greedy". Basically, greedy means that the expression will find everything up to the last `'` in the whole string while lazy means it will stop as soon as it finds the first `'`.

[This is probably a better explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions#2301298).